# I can't register data after validating it with Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with my project. When I enter data without making a mistake, the data is correctly registered in my database, but when I want to register empty data and field validation is activated with Data Annotatios, the flow continues towards the next view but no information is registered. How could I solve it?

Controller:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult RegistroSolicitudes(int idprof)
{
    ViewBag.idprof = idprof;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult RegistroSolicitudes(TB_Solicitudes s, int id)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SP_REGISTRO_SOLICITUDES(s.TITULOSOL, s .NOMBRE, s.APELLIDO, s.CELULAR, s .DISTRITO, s.DESCRIPCI, s.IDPROFESI,.IDCLIENTE, s.ESTADO);
            
            return RedirectToAction ("ListadoSolicitudesPorUsuario",
                new { id  = id });
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
    
    return View();

}
```

In the view I am using this code to activate only the POST method:

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Registrar Solicitud", "RegistroSolicitudes",
    new { id = @Session["IDUSUARIO"] },
    new { @class = "btn btn-primary",
          @onclick = "$(this).parents('form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href'));$(this).parents('form').submit();return false;" })
```

Comment: seems that stored procedure SP_REGISTRO_SOLICITUDES didn't save null values

Comment: the database if it stores null values

Comment: @Emmanuel please include your class code for `TB_Solicitudes`

Comment: Have you confirmed the the `ModelState` is actually invalid when you hit the line `if (ModelState.IsValid)` ?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you saying that the `Model.IsValid` condition is tripping, instead of returning the user to the view with model errors? Or are you saying they're returned to the view, as expected, but their data isn't persisting? You say "the flow continues towards the next view but no information is registered", which sounds like the former, but that's confusing as your logic suggests it should _not_ continue "towards the next view" if `ModelState.IsValid` is false.